# Listview Filter C#, WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, filter, textbox

I would make listview filter with textbox something like that:
http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-filtering/

```
public void connect()
{
    con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=fujitsu;user id=***;password=***;
                            Initial Catalog=ADDRESS_BOOK;Integrated Security=True");

    string qry = "select * from ksiazka";
    adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(qry, con);
    dtForGridView = new DataTable();
    adpt.Fill(dtForGridView);
    lista.ItemsSource = dtForGridView.DefaultView;
}
```

And my listview

```
<ListView Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Name="lista"
    Margin="10,0,0,-375" BorderThickness="0" SelectionChanged="lista_SelectionChanged">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Width="50"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding nr}"
                            Header="NR" />
            <GridViewColumn Width="187" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding nazwa}"
                            Header="Nazwa klienta" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Can someone help me make that filter to my program. I will be very grateful.

Comment: `DataView` (result of `dtForGridView.DefaultView`) has [`RowFilter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.rowfilter(v=vs.110).aspx) for that

Comment: `private void szukajka_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
  dtForGridView.DefaultView.RowFilter = "nazwa='" + szukajka.Text.Trim() + "'";
  }` I made this but when I put some character to textbox, items in list disappear

Comment: Not sure I understand but it will try to match exactly what you type in `TextBox`. If you want to perform partial match you need to use _LIKE_ `"nazwa LIKE '*" + szukajka.Text.Trim() + "*'"` [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Ahh now I got another problem. I'm using `int temp = lista.SelectedIndex;` `nr.Text = dtForGridView.Rows[temp][0].ToString();` in lista_SelectionChanged. But with filter row don't change of course. Can someone help me again?

Comment: since this is completely different issue you need to ask another question

Comment: Okey thanks for fast answer :)